# FillingStyle and Opacity won't work together in Mathematica

Tags: plotting, color, style

I try to plot some data in *Mathematica* using the `ListLinePlot[]`.
Unfortunately the plot option `ColorFunction`, `Filling` and `FillingStyle` won't work together. For example:

```
ListLinePlot[data1D,
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
  ColorFunctionScaling -> True,
  PlotStyle -> Thick,
  Filling -> Axis
]
```

will give me the following result:

[image: ListLinePlot w.o. Opacity]

The issue with this plot is the missing opacity. You can barely see the axes label and it gets worse when you use multiple functions.
The `FillingStyle` option gives theoretically the possibility to change the opacity. Adding the following line to my code

```
FillingStyle -> Opacity[0.1]
```

gives me some opacity but unfortunately I lose the `ColorFunction`:

[image: ListLinePlot with Opacity]

Does somebody have any idea how to use `Filling`, `FillingStyle`, `Opacity` and `ColorFunction` together?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get both the `Opacity` and the mapping of the colour to the function value not the x-coordinate, try this:

```
ListLinePlot[data1D, PlotStyle -> {Opacity[0.4]}, Filling -> Axis, 
 ColorFunction -> 
  Function[{horiz, vert}, Opacity[.7, ColorData["Rainbow"][vert]]]]
```

The trick is to make the pure function have two arguments, but only use the second.

[image]

Comment: works perfectly! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you have to add the opacity to the colorfunction or you get some kind of an error in your color function and it turns to a grey colored blank.

```
ListLinePlot[data1D, PlotStyle -> {Opacity[0.4]}, Filling -> Axis, 
ColorFunction -> Function[f, Opacity[.7, ColorData["Rainbow"][f]]]]
```

note you can remove that Plotstyle.

```
ListLinePlot[data1D, Filling -> Axis, 
ColorFunction -> Function[f, Opacity[.5, ColorData["Rainbow"][f]]]]
```

[image]

Edit:

As Verbeia mentioned all the possibilities with colorfunction are viable, and you can set to colorfunction to change with respect the vertical axes.

```
ListLinePlot[data1D, Filling -> Axis, 
ColorFunction -> 
Function[{x, y}, Opacity[.5, ColorData["Rainbow"][y]]]
]
```

[image]

Comment: This is good but doesn't quite replicate what he is looking for, which maps the colour value to the function value, not the x-coordinate.

Comment: yes, you are right, I was mentioning the issue forgot the vertical part.

Answer (score 2):

### BaseStyle

```
data1 = Accumulate[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 250]];
ListLinePlot[data1, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotStyle -> Thick, 
 Filling -> Axis, BaseStyle -> FaceForm[Opacity[.3]]]
```

[image]

### Post-processing

```
ListLinePlot[data1, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotStyle -> Thick, Filling -> Axis] /.
 p_Polygon :> {Opacity[.3], p}
```

[image]